# Elasticsearch stays in initializing stage, without actually working or throwing an error

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using **Elasticsearch** version **6.4.3**, and it was working as expected until today morning.

When I run `elasticsearch.exe`, it stays in initializing state, without throwing any errors.

**elasticsearch.log**

```
[2022-06-07T12:17:24,504][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [JO01HQESKAVM02] initializing ...
[2022-06-07T12:17:24,770][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [JO01HQESKAVM02] using [1] data paths, mounts [[(C:)]], net usable_space [136.2gb], net total_space [499.4gb], types [NTFS]
[2022-06-07T12:17:24,770][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [JO01HQESKAVM02] heap size [15.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
```

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
cluster.name: elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
node.name: JO01HQESKAVM02
path.data: C:\ELK\Elasticsearch\data
path.logs: C:\ELK\Elasticsearch\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
path.repo: ["/mount/backups", "/mount/longterm_backups"]
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

any help?

[image]

Comment: I suggest to run a checkdisk first.